# Magento 1.x: Widget custom parameter

Tags: php, magento, widget, magento-1.9

I've created a widget called `XXX Widget`. That widget only contains one custom type field. Below you'll see an example of my `widget.xml`, there you'll see that I call a custom renderer in `<type>...</type>`. You can also see that I've added a custom parameter called `HAMBURGER` (just an example).

The custom renderer is displayed, so far so good. But my question is: Is there a way for me to grab the `hamburger` value in my custom renderer (`xxx.phtml`)?

I really wish my English was better, and my programming skills...

Cheers!

**etc/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <xxx type="xxx_xxx/xxx" translate="name">
        <name>XXX Widget</name>
        <parameters>
            <ratio translate="label description">
                <label>Hello</label>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <type>xxx_xxx/adminhtml_widget_renderer_xxx</type>
                <HAMBURGER>with cheese</HAMBURGER>
            </ratio>
        </parameters>
    </xxx>
</widgets>
```

**Xxx/Xxx/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Renderer/Xxx.php**

```
class xxx_xxx_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Renderer_Xxx
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('xxx/renderer/xxx.phtml');
    }

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

}
```

**adminhtml/default/default/template/xxx/renderer/xxx.phtml**

```
<tr>
  <td class="label">
      <label>
          <?php echo $this->getElement()->getLabel(); ?>
          <?php if ($this->getElement()->getRequired()): ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?>
      </label>
  </td>
  <td class="value">
      <input type="text"
             class="widget-option input-text <?php if ($this->getElement()->getRequired()): ?>required-entry<?php endif; ?>"
             name="<?php echo $this->getElement()->getName(); ?>"
             id="<?php echo $this->getElement()->getHtmlId(); ?>"
             value="<?php echo $this->getElement()->getValue(); ?>">

      <p class="note">
          <span><?php echo HAMBURGER; ?></span>
      </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```